# Time to microseconds over 24hrs in php

Tags: php

I have to convert time in format of hh:mm:ss which is over 24hr, for instance 34:23:00. Is there any simple solution for this without using explode + strtotime functions?

Comment: In which format do you receive this data? How does your code look now?

Comment: Did u try any solution?

Comment: and 34:23:00 will give you what ?

Comment: strrotime with over 24 hr will output blank. Data is from transport planning system which is in hh:mm:ss. I can build function which will count ammount of 24hrs in time and convert to miliseconds whatever left plus strtotime(24:00:00) but i was wondering if this can be achieved simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you're looking for (assuming 1 second = 1000000 microseconds).

```
$time = '34:23:00';
$parts = explode(':', $time);   
$hours = !empty($parts[0]) ? $parts[0] : 0;
$minutes = !empty($parts[1]) ? $parts[1] : 0;
$seconds = !empty($parts[2]) ? $parts[2] : 0;

$microseconds = (($hours * 60 * 60) + ($minutes * 60) + ($seconds)) * 1000000;
```

Comment: Im assuming that there is no straigth metod like strtotime to convert this. I will use math @Davis solution instead. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
<?php
$inputTime = "34:23:00";
$timeSplitted = explode(":", $inputTime);
$microSeconds = ($timeSplitted[0]*3600 + $timeSplitted[1]*60 + $timeSplitted[2]*1)*1000;
var_dump($microSeconds); // int(123780000)
```